# An example of posterior distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

I am learning statistics myself. The question might be trivial but it's not a homework problem.

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and $k$ be a smaller one. Suppose $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n$ are IID Bernoulli random variable $B(\theta)$ with an unknown $\theta$. Let $X$ be $\frac{X_1 + \cdots X_n}{n}$. Suppose $k$ is the observed $X$. Then

$$P(X=\frac{k}{n}\,|\,\theta) = {n \choose k} \theta^k (1-\theta)^{n-k} \, [k \in \{0 \cdots n\}]. $$

Fix $a \in [0,1]$. I'm interested in calculating how likely the underlying model $\theta$ is $a$. I hope to do it by the Bayesian formula:

$$
P(\theta = a| X=k) = \frac{P(X=k|\theta = a) P(\theta=a)}{P(X=k)}.
$$

However, I cannot think of what $P(X = k)$ and $P(\theta = a)$ are. Am I missing anything?

Comment: If this is supposed to be Bayesian then you should decide the prior distribution of $\theta$.

Comment: Then $P(X=k)=\int P(X=k \mid \theta = a) P(\theta=a)\, da$ (or a sum if $a$ has  a discrete distribution)

Comment: @Henry Oh so do I also need to specify a measure $da$? Also, can I say that as $n$ goes to infinity, the posterior distribution (LHS) is going to tend to some universal limit, no matter which specific prior distribution one starts with? (possibly related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3905191/intuitive-meaning-of-definettis-theorem-by-specific-examples)

Comment: If you go down the measure theory route, Bayes theorem looks something like $\dfrac{d\mu_{\Theta\mid X}}{d\mu_\Theta}(\theta \mid x)
= \dfrac{f_{X\mid \Theta}(x\mid \theta)}{\int\limits_\Omega f_{X\mid\Theta}(x\mid t) \, d\mu_\Theta(t)}$ so I tend to avoid it.  But yes, you need a prior distribution or measure (perhaps I should have said for $\theta$ rather than for $a$)

Comment: Note too:  When $X=\dfrac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{n}$, then $X$ is **not** binomially distributed. Rather, you will have $(nX\mid\theta)\sim\mathcal{Binom}(n,\theta)$, so: $$\mathsf P(\underset{\uparrow\text{ note}}{\underbrace{n\, X}= k\mid \theta}) = \binom nk \theta^k(1-\theta)^{n-k}~\mathbf 1_{k\in[[0..n]]}$$

Comment: @Henry That makes sense! So if I start with a prior distribution or measure, then with $k$ fixed and $a$ varying, I'd have a (called posterior?) distribution (LHS). Would that distribution tends to a universal one as $n \to \infty$, regardless which prior distribution one chooses?

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thanks! Have edited the question accordingly!

Comment: If you choose a continuous prior distribution for $\theta$ with positive density on $(0,1)$ then the limiting distribution is a point probability concentrated at the actual value of $\theta$.  But suppose your prior had been $P(\theta=\frac14)=P(\theta=\frac34)=\frac12$,  then if the actual value of $\theta$ was $\frac12$ there would be no limiting distribution while if the actual value of $\theta$ was $\frac13$ then the limiting distribution would be concentrated at $\frac14$.

Answer (score 1):

Your model is Bernoulli. Thus the likelihood you observe will be

$$p(\mathbf{x}|\theta)\propto \theta^k(1-\theta)^{n-k}$$

The posterior distribution is the following

$$\pi(\theta|\mathbf{x}) \propto\pi(\theta) p(\mathbf{x}|\theta)$$

To derive your posterior now you have some different choices to set your prior

1. You have no information about the parameter so it can take any values in $[0;1]$ with the same probability: $\pi(\theta)=1$ and your posterior is

$$\pi(\theta|\mathbf{x}) \propto \theta^k(1-\theta)^{n-k} \sim Beta(k+1;n-k+1)$$

That is

$$\pi(\theta|\mathbf{x})=\frac{\Gamma(n+2)}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(n-k+1)}\theta^k(1-\theta)^{n-k}$$

$\theta \in [0;1]$

2. You have some information about the values of the parameter...it is more probabily that $\theta \in A \subset [0;1]$ so you can use a conjugate prior and do the same calcualtion as in 1.
3. You can use a non informative prior (EDIT: not exactly what Jeffrey proposed) that in this case can be in the form

$$\pi(\theta)\propto \frac{1}{\theta(1-\theta)}$$

and your posterior becomes

$$\pi(\theta|\mathbf{x})\propto\theta^{k-1}(1-\theta)^{n-k-1}$$

Which is always a beta with differen paramenters:

$$\pi(\theta|\mathbf{x})\sim Beta(k,n-k)$$

in this case, your posterior is a density only if $0<k<n$ because in the extremes situation of no successes or all successes, the posterior is not integrable

4. et cetera et cetera

Comment: I am not sure $\pi(\theta)\propto \frac{1}{\theta(1-\theta)}$ is a Jeffreys' prior - it looks more like a Haldane prior to me while the Jeffreys' prior would be $\pi(\theta)\propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{\theta(1-\theta)}}$

Comment: But no matter.  The point is that the Beta is conjugate to the Binomial so with any Beta prior everything is proportional to $\theta^\alpha(1-\theta)^\beta$ and all you have to do is keep track of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the prior, likelihood and posterior, acknowledging that there is also a normalizing constant.

Comment: @Henry : yes  you are right. I proposed a non informative prior to show that the posterior could be a density with some restrictions.

Comment: Doesn't $\pi(\theta)$ have to be chosen so that its integration is $1$ over $[0,1]$? If that's the case, isn't the choice in 3 invalid?

Comment: @Student:  it is exactly what I wanted to underline...it is a "non informative prior" an "invalid prior" but leading to a valid posterior

Comment: So starting from a choice of $\pi(\theta)$, one arrives to another distribution over $\theta$. Does it makes sense to treat this posterior distribution as prior distribution, and do it again, and even do it iteratively? By doing so, can one expect obtaining a limit under good conditions?